# ¿Como creo este tipo de AlertDialog en android?

Tags: android, alertdialog

soy nuevo en la programación android y me gustaría saber como crear estos tipos de alerta con el titulo en celeste mas la linea de subrayado ya que los que he probado me los crea diferentes a este estilo.

[image: Imagen del AlertDialog que quiero (sin el nivel de brillo, solo el mensaje)]

Comment: Bienvenido.Mauro.., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: Lo mejor seria que crees un dialog personalizado en vez de un AlertDialog , con Dialog podes modificar mas a tu gusto como se va a mostrar

Comment: muestra tu código java, que muestre lo que has intentado

Comment: No creo que ya haga falta publicar mi codigo, Leandro ya me dio la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Hola mauro que tal haga de enseño como crear un dialogo perzonalizado :

1- Crearemos un xml para el dialogo que sera este :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Brillo"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/blue" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Brillo automatico"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancelar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Aceptar" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

2- Creamos una clase llamada GlitterDialog que se encargara de la creacion del dialogo :

```
public class GlitterDialog {

private AlertDialog alertDialog;
private OptionsGlitter optionsGlitter;

GlitterDialog(Activity activity) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    View view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.glitter_dialog, null);
    alertBuilder.setView(view);

    Button buttonOne = view.findViewById(R.id.one_button);
    Button buttonTwo = view.findViewById(R.id.two_button);

    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            optionsGlitter.cancel();
        }
    });

    buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            optionsGlitter.accept();
        }
    });

    alertDialog = alertBuilder.create();
}

public void show() {
    alertDialog.show();
}

public void cancel() {
    alertDialog.cancel();
}

interface OptionsGlitter {
    void cancel();

    void accept();
}

public void setOnclickOptionsGlitter(OptionsGlitter optionsGlitter) {
    this.optionsGlitter = optionsGlitter;
}
}
```

Al llamarlo al activity seria de esta forma :

```
private GlitterDialog glitterDialog;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    glitterDialog = new GlitterDialog(this);
    glitterDialog.setOnclickOptionsGlitter(new GlitterDialog.OptionsGlitter() {
        @Override
        public void cancel() {
            glitterDialog.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void accept() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Completo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            glitterDialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            glitterDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Te esta forma puedes reusar tus dialogos de la manera mas sencilla.

[image]

--Espero que de ayude

Comment: Hola Leandro, bienvenido a SOes. Mira [answer] para ver cuando hay que respondery como a las preguntas. Como respuesta es muy buena pero deberías haber esperado a que el usuario editase su pregunta y la ampliase.